# view commandline with compile matlab exe

Tags: matlab, command-line, executable

I have a matlab gui which works in matlab but if I compile it to a gui, the application
does not respond on buttons and somehow does not work.

Now I would like to see all error messages, but I can not because there is no commandline anymore.

Can I switch on a commandline ouput window for matlab executables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can simply run he exe from a dos shell. Alle comand line output will be available in the dos shell.